# "Graphing" one number within a large range

Tags: java, math, gwt, html5-canvas, graphing

In short, I'm trying to make a bar (using GWT's wrapper for HTML5 canvas) that will show something reasonable for a given value, no matter what the value of the bottom and top of the chart actually are. I'm assuming the best approach is logarithmic, but I'm completely open to any other solution.

Assumptions:

- Our "bar" vertical, measuring 200 pixels high, 35 pixels wide.
- We're showing a "site" versus it's parent "region". The units are ones of power (e.g. kW, MW, GW).
- The "region" has a range of 1 kW to 55.19 GW. The average value is 27.6 MW.
- Approximately 95% of sites within the region are much closer to 1 W than 55 GW, but the top 5% skew the average significantly.
- The `first site` has a value of `12.67 MW`. The `second site` has a value of `192.21 kW`.

Obviously the second site wouldn't even register on a linear graph, while the first would register very low.

How can I make this bar more useful? For example, I'd like the top 5% of sites that skew the region's average to represent only a small portion (5%) of the total bar, while the other 95% should represent 95%.

[image: Conceptual Image of Problem]

The line in the lower area of the bar is the region average line, while the entire bar represents Minimum (bottom) to Maximum (top).

Current Java code using log10:

```
// BAR_GRAPH_WIDTH = 36, BAR_GRAPH_HEIGHT = 200
// regionNsp (MW): [min=0.0, max=55192.8, avg=27596.5] 
// siteNsp (MW) = 187.18
DrawingArea canvas = new DrawingArea(BAR_GRAPH_WIDTH, BAR_GRAPH_HEIGHT);
Rectangle bgRect = new Rectangle(1, 0, BAR_GRAPH_WIDTH - 1, BAR_GRAPH_HEIGHT); // backgound bar
bgRect.setFillColor("white");
canvas.add(bgRect);
int graphSize = (int)(BAR_GRAPH_HEIGHT / Math.log10(regionNsp.getMax()));
int siteHeight = (int)Math.log10(siteNsp - regionNsp.getMin()) * graphSize;
Rectangle valueRect = new Rectangle(1, BAR_GRAPH_HEIGHT-siteHeight, 35, siteHeight);
valueRect.setFillColor("lightgreen");
canvas.add(valueRect);
```

Comment: I can't picture what you are describing - is it a single bar split into two coloured regions, or two bars next to each other, or many bars for the many sites within a region?

Comment: We're charting ONE site versus the region at a time. Think of it as a Site Summary.

Comment: added an image to help conceptualize what we're doing here.

Comment: @Jonathan M: Yes and no- I got here an idea but nothing concrete to run with. I was hoping to get a more clear answer, or a revision to an existing answer. If neither happens, I'll take one of these tomorrow AM.

Comment: @Chris: Tell a bit more of what your wanting. By concrete, do you mean an exact algorithm?

Comment: That'd be helpful, pseudo-code is completely acceptable. I have been attempting to work this out in Java code, but the results still seem skewed. Most sites do appear in the middle area, but the lower 40% still don't register at all.

Comment: Go ahead and post your java. Maybe we can mod that.

Comment: Added Java code for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I admit that I don't know much about GWT, so I'm answering on the basis of how would I show your values on a paper-and-pencil graph.  That answer is that you've answered your own question - use logs.  The range from 1000 to 55200000000 with an average around 27600000, after taking (common base 10) logs, becomes about 3 to 11, with the average around 7.4.

The caveat is that what you gain in "reasonableness" you do loose in perspective.  Take the decibel scale, which is (common base 10) log based.  The difference between an 80 decibel sound and an 85 decibel sound doesn't seem like a big change, except that the second is *three times* more energetic.

Comment: paper-and-pencil math would be fine- how might you do the calculation?

Comment: In Java, `double x = Math.log10(y);` where y is the actual energy value, and x is what you will show on the graph.

Comment: Note that you don't have to use log10 - experiment with different logarithms. The math class doesn't provide a log(b, x) method directly, but you can use `double x = Math.log(y) / Math.log(b)` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base)

Comment: @Chris Lercher: Thanks, I'll check it out. Sounds like a good bet.

Comment: I concur with the last comment, and I editied my answer to make it clear that I was referring to the common, or base 10, log.  But a natural log or other base would also do the job.  Perhaps as Chris mentions, with a little experimenting you can find one that fits your 200 pixel height without additional scaling.

Answer (score 3):

Consider logarithmic scale with a break for extremely high values that are far beyond any others in the population. For an example of a break in the bars and axis, see: http://tomhopper.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/bar-chart-natural-axis-split1.png